# Ports 1935 and 843 are getting blocked for no reason

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, port, tcp

I have Windows 7, and my computer has been blocking ports 1935 and 843 for no reason for a while now. If for example, I try to watch twitch, nothing will work because those two are getting blocked.

Here is what I've tried to no avail:

1) Tried different browsers
2) Turned off Firewall
3) Tried making ALLOW rules on windows firewall for those two ports

So I've ruled out firewall or any weird browser issues. It is not an issue with our router either because on all of the other computers in our place twitch works fine, but on my computer even in different places twitch does not work.

netstat -an shows this:
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63154     199.9.248.102:843      SYN_SENT
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63156     199.9.248.177:1935     SYN_SENT
netstat -o shows this:
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63159     stackoverflow:http     ESTABLISHED     5768
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63161     cp:https               CLOSE_WAIT      5768
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63163     video23:1935           SYN_SENT        5768
netstat -anobv shows this:
[chrome.exe]
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63321     199.9.248.102:843      SYN_SENT        5768
[chrome.exe]
 TCP    192.168.1.68:63323     199.9.248.177:1935     SYN_SENT        5768

Anyway, I looked at all these and it showed that chrome was the ONLY thing that was associated with those two ports on my computer. I'm stumped now -- what could be blocking these ports? Is there anything I can do besides reformatting the entire thing?

BTW, on my linux partition, everything works fine... it's just that on the few rare times I have to be on Windows I'd rather not put everything on hold and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Both are Adobe Flash ports.  I know that Microsoft did a blacklist on several sites using Flash.  Thought that was Win8 only.  Try and uninstall/reinstall Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: I doubt that that'd do anything, because chrome comes with flash, and I mainly use chrome. Just tried it for the hell of it, did nothing. :/